# Macro changing format of unreferenced cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've got something weird happening in a macro worksheet. I have a macro that runs an SQL statement, and then copies the returned table into a worksheet. However, for some reason, the line of code below:

```
oWorkSheet.Cells(iRow + 1, iColumn).CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

changes three cells on a different worksheet (not the one it is pasting the data on) from number format to date format. It's got me completely stumped. The three cells aren't next to each other - just scattered throughout the sheet.

Any thoughts? I know I could just put in some code to change the format back, but that seems messy.

Comment: Sure there are no triggers involved?

Comment: Take a look for these two words in the code: `_Change` and `_SelectionChange`, using `Ctrl+F`, and `Current Project` on the radio button.

Comment: Are those cells formatted in Normal style?

Comment: Yes, they are formatted Normal Style.There are no triggers involved. _Change and _SelectionChange to do appear anywhere in the project